# How to validate in model in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. Now I am starting to develop a project using Laravel 5. I have been using CodeIgniter before. I am having problem with validation class that is not compatible with what I want to do.

Normally we validate in Controller like this.

```
    public function postCreate(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:30',
            'mm_name' => 'required|max:50',
        ]);

        echo "passed";
    }
```

That is working find. But what I want to do is I want to move that validation logic to model. So I created a new folder called Models under app folder. Under the Models folder I created a class called ValidationHelper that extends the Model class.

This is my Validation helper class

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class ValidationHelper extends Model{

    function CreateCategory($request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:30',
            'mm_name' => 'required|max:50',
        ]);
    }   

}
```

So now I am trying to import that class to my controller using constructor dependency injection. So now my controller is like this.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\ValidationHelper;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    protected $validationHelper;

    function __construct(ValidationHelper $v_helper)
    {
        $this->validationHelper = $v_helper;
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function categoryList()
    {
        //
        return View('admin.Category.list');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return View('admin.Category.create');
    }

}
```

So when I run my app and do validation, it is giving me this error. How can I do this in Laravel? How to separate my validation logic to model?

Comment: would mind if tell me what is the error?

Comment: What is the reason of moving the validation logic in the model and not to its own specific class ?

Comment: The reason is I want my code follow the SOLID rule. Especially single resposiblity.Cause in asp.net mvc , I can achieve it very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the code in your model by registering model event(s) as given below:

```
// For example, User.php model
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($user)
    {
        if (!$user->isValid()) return false;
    }
}
```

If you put this `boot` method in your `User.php` model then whenever you'll create a new user, the validation will take place at first. For this, you have to create the `isValid` method in your model where you'll check the validation by yourself and return true/false depending on the validation result. If you return false, creation will be inturupted. This is just an idea but you may [read more here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events) about model events.

Comment: Is this only for eloquent entity ?

Comment: Yes, only for `Eloquent` create action in this case.